# Can column values be modified during sync using adldap2-laravel

Tags: laravel, ldap, adldap

Have been tasked with moving authentication for an existing web-app from Laravel auth to LDAP.
For existing users it works well except some small issues because of an already populated user table.

An employee # format we use is different between LDAP and the user table. LDAP has 'User Id:' prepending the number. The local user table does not. Is there a way to make modifications to column values before they update/sync the user table? In this case remove 'User Id:' from the value before updating. BTW this is NOT being used as the username.

Thanks.

Laravel Version: 6.1.5

Adldap2-Laravel Version: 6.1.5

PHP Version: 7.2

LDAP Type: ActiveDirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found section on Attribute Handlers in docs. https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2-Laravel/#/auth/setup

This was what I needed.